# How to write html inside IPython Dialog box?

Tags: javascript, python, html, ipython, jupyter-notebook

How can I write html as html (not as HTML String) inside IPython Dialog?

For example: I have a Ipython UI Extension that shows a Dialog box

```
require(
    ["base/js/dialog"], 
    function(dialog) {
        dialog.modal({
            title: 'Hello world',
            body: ?? ,
            buttons: {
                'schedule': {}
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Now inside body of the dialog box, I want to show following HTML content.

```
    <label>Quick Schedule</label><br />

    <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="schedule = '@reboot'; job_string();">Startup</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="schedule = '@hourly'; job_string();">Hourly</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="schedule = '@daily'; job_string();">Daily</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="schedule = '@weekly'; job_string();">Weekly</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="schedule = '@monthly'; job_string();">Monthly</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="schedule = '@yearly'; job_string();">Yearly</a><br /><br />

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">Minute</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">Hour</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">Day</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">Month</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">Week</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="job-minute" value="*" onclick="this.select();"/></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="job-hour" value="*" onclick="this.select();"/></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="job-day" value="*" onclick="this.select();"/></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="job-month" value="*" onclick="this.select();"/></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="job-week" value="*" onclick="this.select();"/></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="set_schedule();">Set</a></div>
    </div>
```

How can I show this HTML content? Lead here is really appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer answer in [HTML String via jQuery append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312451/html-string-via-jquery-append)

Tip: Write extensions for Jupyter Lab instead that supports writing Typescripts too.